# how to implement dynamic tabs use react native router flux?

Tags: react-native-router-flux

- react-native 0.38.1
- react-native-router-flux 3.37.0

  I want to implement dynamic tabs base on authentication, when user login, show Home and Profile tabs, otherwise show Home tab only

  I use `Switch` but not work.

  ```
   <Scene key="tabbar"
     tabs
     type={ActionConst.RESET}
     initial
     hideNavBar
     tabBarStyle={ styles.tabBar }
     pressOpacity={1}
     default="main">

       <Scene key="main"
           title="Home"
           type="switch"
           icon={TabHomeIcon}
           hideNavBar
           component={Main}
           initial/>

      <Scene key="profile"
          title="Profile"
          type="switch"
          icon={TabMeIcon}
          hideNavBar
          component={Profile}/>
  </Scene>
  ```

Comment: I have the same question. @dome. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the example from the docs:

```
<Scene
    key="root"
    component={connect(state=>({profile:state.profile}))(Switch)}
    tabs={true}
    unmountScenes
    selector={props=>props.profile.sessionID ? "main" : "signUp"}
    >
    <Scene key="signUp" component={SignUp}/>
    <Scene key="main" component={Main}>
</Scene>
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.